# How do I enable unprivileged_userns_clone selectively for one executable or user?

Tags: linux, security, group, capabilities, userns

How do I enable `CLONE_NEWUSER` in a more fine-grained fashion compared to just `kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone`?

I want to keep kernel API attack surface manageable by keeping new and complicated things like non-root `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` or BPF disabled, but also selectively allow it for some specific programs.

For example, `chrome-sandbox` wants either `CLOSE_NEWUSER` or suid-root for proper operation, but I don't want all the programs to be able to use such complicated tricks, only a handful of approved ones.

Comment: Update: I believe there is a way to do this with AppArmor now. I'll edit my answer later to give details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without creating a custom kernel patch, this isn't possible. Note that this particular Debian-specific sysctl [is deprecated](https://www.debian.org/releases/bullseye/amd64/release-notes/ch-information.en.html#linux-user-namespaces). The way to disable user namespaces is `user.max_user_namespaces = 0`.

A new user namespace is created by [`kernel/user_namespace.c:create_user_ns()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0/source/kernel/user_namespace.c#L81). There are several checks that occur prior to allowing the creation of a new namespace, but nothing indicates the ability to control this on a per-file or per-user basis. It's unfortunate, but many kernel developers [don't understand the risk](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/209533/106285) behind enabling unprivileged user namespaces on a global basis.

A sample (untested!) patch to allow only UID 1234 to create a new namespace in kernel 6.0:

```
--- a/kernel/user_namespace.c
+++ b/kernel/user_namespace.c
@@ -86,6 +86,10 @@ int create_user_ns(struct cred *new)
    struct ucounts *ucounts;
    int ret, i;
 
+   ret = -EPERM;
+   if (!uid_eq(current_uid(), KUIDT_INIT(1234)))
+       goto fail;
+
    ret = -ENOSPC;
    if (parent_ns->level > 32)
        goto fail;
```